# help needed with inactivated option for wcs in SAO Image DS9

Tags: ds9

Another trouble in SAOImae DS9: with the Rotation Measure catalogue I have just downloaded: “Rotation measure image of the sky (Taylor+2009)”, even if I have set up the WCS to galactic before the catalogue loadind, I obtain the table file with another WCS (and the option to chane WCSto another one is inactivated); then I can not obtain from it the galactic longitude and altitude needed for my report..

Comment: Did you try creating your own region files from the catalogue?

Comment: yes.I check that the world co-ordinate system selected is ‘Galactic’ and ‘Sexagesimal’ and I enter l=005 and b=24. then I type into the width box ‘15’ and the height box ‘15 ‘ and select ‘degrees’.  I obtain a card with no galactic coordonate !

Comment: What I meant is, after you select the catalogue and filter the objects you want, you should export the database to a text file. Then, check the text file if there are information you need.